# Divergence proof for a second kind improper integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I managed to prove$\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{{{\left( 1-{{x}^{2}} \right)}^{5}}}}=\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{\left( 1-x \right)}^{\frac{5}{3}}}{{\left( 1+x \right)}^{\frac{5}{3}}}}>\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{1-x}>0$, besides I also showed that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{1-x}dx}$ diverges, so $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{{{\left( 1-{{x}^{2}} \right)}^{5}}}}dx}$ must also diverge. This proof is quite tedious and clumsy. I was wondering perhaps there is a shorter/more elegant way to show that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{{{\left( 1-{{x}^{2}} \right)}^{5}}}}dx}$, indeed, diverges?

Comment: You claim that you have a "tedious and clumsy" proof of this fact.  However, if we can't see that proof, how are we to know that any  proof given as an answer is not exactly the same argument?  Please include your original proof in this question.  Please also give us some background.  Why are you interested in the divergence of this integral?  What background do you have?  What theorems might be applicable here?  Please edit your question to include some additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by $1-x^2=u$

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{{{\left( 1-{{x}^{2}} \right)}^{5}}}}dx}=\frac12\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{u^{\frac53}}du}$$

which diverges by LCT with $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{u^{\frac53}}du}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For $0<x<1$, try to show the following inequality:
$$
\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(1-x^2)^5}} \geq \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}.
$$
Then, compute
$$
F(x) := \int \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}dx
$$
and you'll see that $F(x)$ diverges for $x \to 1$, so in particular your original integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The limit comparison test is the quickest way ;

Near $ 1^-,$ we have

$$(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x)\sim 2(1-x)$$ so

$$\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^{\frac 53}} \sim \frac{1}{2^{\frac 53}(1-x)^{\frac 53}}$$

and
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1-x)^\frac 53}\text{ is divergent}$$

since $\frac 53\ge 1$.